# Is it possible to run embedded WebKit on Windows Phone?

Tags: windows-phone, webkit, sencha-touch

There we have an web app developed for Android and iPhone (using webview). It is based on Sencha Touch 1.1.1. Thus it runs only on WebKit based browsers, and not on Internet Explorer. I want it to run it on Windows Phone, thus I need to run WebKit (not IE) inside the app (as webview).

Is it possible to build a Windows app with webview which used WebKit?

Comment: I'm not sure what you've developed, but Sencha Touch's web site says: "Sencha Touch applications work on every mobile browser" and "Win Phone 8.1 (with IE11)". In fact, that is the whole point of using a framework such as this or Cordova. Can you explain why you need Webkit?

Comment: Sencha Touch 1 works only in WebKit, because at that time Windows Phone didn't exist. Sencha Touch 2.2 and above supports Internet Explorer https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?259109-Does-Sencha-Touch-2-now-support-IE-10

Comment: You can try http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/examples/production/kitchensink/ You will see that Sencha Touch 1 works only it WebKit based browsers.